# c# how to make thread wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Form form1 = new Form();
Thread newThread = new Thread(() => 
        form = form1
);
newThread.Start();
while(form == null)
{
     WAIT? 
}
```

Can anyone help me how to make thread wait befor going on with execution? And not to use thread.sleep?

Comment: Why is the reason you don't want to use `Thread.Sleep`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Form form1 = new Form();
Thread newThread = new Thread(() => {
        form = form1;
        mre.Set();
});
newThread.Start();
mre.WaitOne();
```

Comment: @user898569: There is some good documentation on msdn regarding event wait handles :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksb7zs2x(v=vs.80).aspx. I strongly recommend you this site for multithreding basics: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @flq: I agree if that's the only thing that thread is doing. But if it really is the only thing, the whole thread seems to be useless. That's why I assumed that the thread is doing more than shown by the OP.

Comment: @0lukasz0: Is this comment addressed to me?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: obviously you are not the one who needs some help here :)

Comment: @0lukasz0: You never know, there is always something to learn :)

Answer (score -1):

as flq mentioned you can use thread.join, that will allow the thread to finish whatever it is doing and you can continue after that point...however since you are working on a forms application you'll probably be blocking the ui thread if you join from there...

you should try a different pattern for fixing this instead of blocking...use delegates or events to signal when something has finished...also known as asynchronous processing.